# How to enable clang-tidy in CMakeLists.txt for Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2019, clang-tidy

Visual Studio 2019 [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/clang-tidy?view) only talks about changing `CMakeSettings.json` to enable `clang-tidy` analysis for a project. How can I do the same in `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: any update on this? Has it being enabled yet

Answer (score 2):

That is not supported at the moment for `CMakeLists.txt`:

> We do not currently support configuration via the `CMAKE_<LANG>_CLANG_TIDY`  variable in CMakeLists.txt in the IDE.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/code-analysis-with-clang-tidy-in-visual-studio/