# Enabling clang-tidy in CMakeLists.txt for Visual Studio Solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, clang

Is it possible to integrate clang tidy using the `CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY` when generating a MSVC solution. I have failed to do so and looking online hasn't helped either. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59185953/15906056) is old but it says it is not supported.

Comment: Voting to close as dup of [How to enable clang-tidy in CMakeLists.txt for Visual Studio 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59185859/how-to-enable-clang-tidy-in-cmakelists-txt-for-visual-studio-2019) I'm pretty sure this is the kind of situation where you just wait for new answer posts. You can put a bounty on that one if you want to attract new answers to it.